# Haskell prime number function not working

Tags: haskell, syntax, primes

I've started learning Haskell in the last couple of days and I'm having trouble with this piece of code. I'm trying to make a function that will generate a list of primes given an initial list (contains at least 2), a maximum list length, the index of the current divisor (should start at 1, tests by dividing current number by all primes so far) and the current number to test (an odd number).

I know it's not very elegant or efficient but this code won't compile or run so I'd like to fix it first before optimizing. Although suggestions on that would be cool too.

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13]

genPrimes primes max curDiv curTest 
  | length primes >= max = primes
  | primes !! curDiv > floor . sqrt curTest = genPrimes (primes ++ [curTest]) max 1 (curTest + 2)
  | curTest `mod` primes !! curDiv == 0 = genPrimes primes max 1 (curTest + 2) 
  | curTest `mod` primes !! curDiv /= 0 = genPrimes primes max (curDiv + 1) curTest
```

I get the following error when I try to compile the above code:

```
Couldn't match expected type `a0 -> c0' with actual type `Integer'
Expected type: [a0 -> c0]
  Actual type: [Integer]
In the first argument of `genPrimes', namely `primes'
In the expression: genPrimes primes 50 1 15
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to post the exact error message in addition to the code that gives you the error. This makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ja. gave already the correct answer, but your solution isn't very idiomatic. Here is an easy way to generate an infinite list of primes:

```
primes = 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]

isPrime n = all ((/=0).(n `mod`)) $ takeWhile (\p -> p*p <= n) primes
```

`primes` is easy to understand, it defines 2 as prime, and inspects all following odd numbers if they are prime. `isPrime` is a little bit more complicated: First we take all primes smaller or equal to the square root of `n`. Then we check if we divide `n` by all of these primes that we have no reminder equal to 0. `isPrime` refers back to `primes`, but this is no problem as Haskell is lazy, and we never need "too much" primes for our check.

The list `primes` is infinite, but you can just write something like `take 10 primes`.

Note that this code has its own problems, see http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: It makes sense, even though lambda expressions are still a little scary for me. But what I don't understand is why this runs somewhat faster than my code, since it is essentially doing the same thing.

Am I correct in understanding that (n `mod`) is just a function with one input? How can you do that without explicitly defining an input?

Comment: @hydroxide better start with [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes].

Answer (score 5):

At the very least your code should be

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13]

genPrimes primes max = go primes (length primes) 1 (last primes + 2)
 where
  go prs len d t 
   | len >= max               = prs
   | (prs !! d) > (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) t
                              = go (prs++[t]) (len+1) 1 (t + 2)
   | t `rem` (prs !! d) == 0  = go  prs        len    1 (t + 2) 
   | t `rem` (prs !! d) /= 0  = go  prs        len  (d + 1)  t

test n = print $ genPrimes primes n
main = test 20
```

Then you reorganize it thus (abstracting away the tests performed for each candidate number, as the `noDivs` function):

```
genPrimes primes max = go primes (length primes) (last primes + 2)
 where
  go prs len t 
   | len >= max      = prs
   | noDivs (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ t) t prs
                     = go (prs++[t]) (len+1) (t + 2)
   | otherwise       = go  prs        len    (t + 2)

noDivs lim t (p:rs)
   | p > lim         = True
   | t `rem` p == 0  = False
   | otherwise       = noDivs lim t rs
```

then you rewrite `noDivs` as

```
noDivs lim t = foldr (\p r -> p > lim || rem t p /= 0 && r) False
```

then you notice that `go` just filters numbers through such that pass the `noDivs` test:

```
genPrimes primes max = take max (primes ++ filter theTest [t, t+2..])
 where
  t = last primes + 2
  theTest t = noDivs (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ t) t
```

but this doesn't work yet, because `theTest` needs to pass `primes` (whole new primes as they are being found) to `noDivs`, but we *are building* this `whole_primes` list (as `take max (primes ++  ...)`), so is there a vicious circle? No, because we only test up to the square root of a number:

```
genPrimes primes max = take max wholePrimes 
 where
  wholePrimes = primes ++ filter theTest [t, t+2..]
  t           = last primes + 2
  theTest t   = noDivs (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ t) t wholePrimes
```

This is working now. But finally, there's nothing special in `genPrimes` now, it's just a glorified call to `take`, and initial `primes` list can actually be shrunk, so we get (changing the arguments arrangement for `noDivs` a little, to make its interface more general):

```
primes = 2 : 3 : filter (noDivs $ tail primes)  [5, 7..]

noDivs factors t = -- return True if the supplied list of factors is too short
  let lim = (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ t) 
  in foldr (\p r-> p > lim || rem t p /= 0 && r) True factors
     -- all ((/=0).rem t) $ takeWhile (<= lim) factors
     -- all ((/=0).rem t) $ takeWhile ((<= t).(^2)) factors
     -- and [rem t f /= 0 | f <- takeWhile ((<= t).(^2)) factors]
```

The global `primes` list is indefinitely defined now (i.e. "infinite"). [Next step](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Segmented_Generate_and_Test) is to realize that between the consecutive squares of primes the length of the list of factors to test by will be the same, incrementing by 1 for each new segment. [Then](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Prime_numbers#Segmented), that having all the factors upfront as the prefix (of known length) of the global `primes` list, we can directly *generate* their multiples (thus each being generated just from its prime factors), instead of testing each number whether it is a multiple of any one of the prime factors below its square root, in sequence.

Comment: Yes it's much nicer, thanks!! I was looking for a way to hide those "helper" variables with recursion -- I've had this problem several times.

Answer (score 4):

You've got the arguments to ':' reversed: the scalar goes to the left, or you can make a singleton list and concatenate:

```
| primes !! curDiv > floor . sqrt curTest = genPrimes (primes++[curTest]) max 1 curTest + 2
```

Comment: Okay thanks, didn't know that. Changed it to concatenate the lists, but now I get a runtime error.. edited my original post.